# How to have transparent background for button?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am develop na UWP app, and I would like to have a transparent button. I try this (Is a simple example of my button):

```
<Button Name="Button"
        Opacity="0">
        <Image Source="/Assets/image.png"/>
</Button>
```

I want a button with an image, in which only the button is transparent. I've tried it that way, and by putting: `Opacity="0"` it puts everything transparent, and I want it to just be transparent.

Comment: Actually you don't need to specify the `Opacity` at all. The `Image` will simply occupy the whole content area of the `Button`.

Comment: If you want to show an Image as button without the borders of the `Button`, you can use `Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"` on the button. But it looks no different from Setting `Tapped` event on `Image` Itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Method 1**

Set `Opacity="0"` for `Button.Background`. You can do it by using below code.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0"/>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

**Method 2**

Set `#00000000` as the background color of the `Button`. Since UWP support [ARGB(Alpha RGB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) color you can directly set opacity for any color in UWP app.

```
<Button Background="#00000000"/>
```

Comment: Simple and effective! Thank you very much!